# Unable to link mysql docker container with spring boot application - Communications link failure

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker-compose

I am new to Docker. I am using Spring boot micro service. It's running well On my local machine. Now, I need to create a docker image for my application. It has a dependency on Mysql server. I am using docker-compose to create my containers. I am getting a communications link failure error while running my custom image (spring boot application). The Mysql image is running well independently.

My yml file :

```
version: '2'

services:

  mysql-dev:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql-dev
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "onlinetutorialspoint"
    networks:
      - my_mysql_net
    ports:
      - 3306:3308

  spring_boot_db_service:
    depends_on:
      - mysql-dev
    image: spring_boot_db_service
    ports:
      - 8181:8181
    links:
      - mysql-dev:mysql
    networks:
      - my_mysql_net

networks:
  my_mysql_net:
    driver: bridge
```

application properties file :

```
db.driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://mysql-dev:3308/onlinetutorialspoint?useSSL=false

spring.datasource.username = root

spring.datasource.password = password
```

Full Error Message :

> spring_boot_db_service_1  | 2019-01-28 13:34:06.955  INFO 1 --- [
>   main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206:
>   hibernate.properties not found spring_boot_db_service_1  | 2019-01-28
>   13:34:07.000  INFO 1 --- [           main]
>   o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate
>   Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final} spring_boot_db_service_1  |
>   2019-01-28 13:34:08.430  WARN 1 --- [           **main]
>   o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain
>   connection to query metadata : Communications link failure**
>   spring_boot_db_service_1  |  spring_boot_db_service_1  | The last
>   packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The
>   driver has not received any packets from the server.
>   spring_boot_db_service_1  | 2019-01-28 13:34:08.443  INFO 1 --- [
>   main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using
>   dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect spring_boot_db_service_1 
>   | 2019-01-28 13:34:08.459  INFO 1 --- [           main]
>   o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000422: Disabling
>   contextual LOB creation as connection was null
>   spring_boot_db_service_1  | 2019-01-28 13:34:08.921  WARN 1 --- [
>   main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'dbServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'dbServiceDao'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   **Error creating bean with name 'dbServiceDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory'** defined in class path
>   resource [com/htc/dbservice/configuration/DBConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
>   spring_boot_db_service_1  | 2019-01-28 13:34:08.923  WARN 1 --- [
>   main] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy
>   method 'close' failed on bean with name 'eurekaRegistration':
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration':
>   Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory
>   are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a
>   destroy method implementation!) spring_boot_db_service_1  | 2019-01-28
>   13:34:08.926  INFO 1 --- [           main]
>   o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
>   docker_spring_boot_db_service_1 exited with code 1

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow buddy! Please take a look at how to format your text, this is not easy to read.

Comment: Can you share the full and exact error message?

Comment: @NicoHaase Thanks for your response, I have added the stack trace in the question section. Thanks

Comment: Did you changed password after first creating the container ? If yes you don't only need to restart the container but also to clean the volume, as Compose is doing some extra stuff to preserve the database state between runs. Also make sure your database is started before your Spring Boot app (you may need a wait script), `links` does not ensure MySQL is started and ready for connections.

Comment: @Yann39 Thanks for your response. As I am using version 2, I have added the https://github.com/Eficode/wait-for sh file in my command section. I also verified the same in the terminal. Still, I am getting the same problem. Command added in yml file :  command: sh -c './wait-for mysql-dev:3306 -- npm start'

Answer (score 1):

Did you change the default mysql port? if not, you are pointing to wrong port number.
When you map the port to pubilsh the service externally, the order is

```
<host-port>:<container-port>
```

```
services:   
   mysql-dev:  
     image: mysql:5.7  
     container_name: mysql-dev  
     environment:  
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"  
       MYSQL_DATABASE: "onlinetutorialspoint"  
     networks:  
       - my_mysql_net  
     ports:  
       - 3308:3306
```

And using docker-compose and connecting both services to the same network you can connect directly to the container without pubishing the mysql port to the external network.
Try to change your spring app pointing to mysql-dev:3306, or try to connect to the  container **spring_boot_db_service** using

```
docker-compose exec spring_boot_db_service bash
```

and make a connectivity test to the database container.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried your solution. Still the problem is not resolved. Note : If I am mentioning dynamic IP address of a mysql docker container then, The application is running fine . i.e jdbc:mysql://172.22.0.2:3306/onlinetutorialspoint?useSSL=false

Comment: Ok, did you change the docker-compose file? If you changed it you would need to recreate the services. Try to execute docker-compose down and UP in order to recreate services. If still not working try to connect to spring app and make a Name resolve test in order to see if there is a problem with the Name.

Comment: Hi, I have checked the open jdk (parent) image  is pointing to 11.0.1. The code I have referred is having lower parent image (version 8). Is Parent image version is really matters for docker configuration?

Comment: Hi, I don't think that matters for docker configuration, but it matters for your code to be compatible. I don't know how your code is implemented but looking into the error message that you posted, the root cause could be compatibility.

Comment: Wow, Thank u so much. Its my mistake only. Now Application is working fine with java 8. Added Parent image as FROM openjdk:8